# How to pass a folder as argument to the executing script?

Tags: scripting, ksh, arguments

I would like to execute a script(h.ksh) with the passing argument `kim` (which is a folder),

so when I run the command

```
 h.ksh kim
```

the folder "kim" will be used as a variable in the h.ksh

Do I need to use the option function?

Comment: Command line args are placed into `$1`, `$2`, etc. So in your example `$1` has the value `kim`.

Comment: I inserted argument="$1" and printf "$argument" into the script file so the $agrument will contain the folder name. Is this right?